# Dojo grid Bool column

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

so I added a check column to my grid with dojo

```
  <th field="selectStudent" width="5%" cellType="dojox.grid.cells.Bool"
      editable="true" alwaysEditing="true">Select Stdent</th>
```

Grid's selection mode is set to **multiple**. I am wondering how do I access(or know)
what all checkboxes user selected?

Comment: Query the grids store.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript on the client side...Examples located here:

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/checkboxes/

Comment: Not what I asked for.... What I know is how to access this checkbox which is embedded inside a grid now.